# Azure security center data, not showing up in Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-security

Let me tell You what issue am facing.

I have followed the link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-powerbi)  in that link Title = (Using Azure Security Center dashboard to access Power BI) in this option 4th is missing in mine.

Procedure I followed

1.when i click the  Explore in Power BI button it opens on the right side and shows the option and I have taken  Security insights dashboard
  after when I click Security insights dashboard it pop up to new window and ask credential of POWER BI in that I have provided the credential of Power BI and login, when it login it will show Connect to Azure Security Center Security Insights window appear

2.Authentication method is oAuth2 with  and other window appear I given aure credential and sign in
**NOTE:-NO content PACK Window appeared and in window appear(connect to azure security center security insight) URL is showing only URL:-https://management.azure.com/subscriptions

3.After all It will show importing data .. BUT no Data will appear ;(

HoPe understand Mine Issue Please Help me TO solve this

THnaking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using your Azure credentials to generate your dashboard in Power BI, and not your Power BI credentials.

The Azure Security Center content pack uses your credentials (the ones you provide after clicking OAuth2) to query Azure's API and get your data into Power BI. You should provide the credentials that have access to your Azure subscriptions, otherwise what you're getting is a dashboard for the Power BI user, which has no Azure credentials and therefore you gets a blank dashboard.

Note that this will only work for organizational accounts (e.g. not hotmail, outlook, etc'). [Here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-azure-security-center/#troubleshooting) is the relevant part from the docs.

Comment: I have provide correct information as you described. Main issue is (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-azure-security-center/#troubleshooting) the 4th option in that URL is not showing